# Static object of a templete class defined in another templete class. Running in linux gives specializing member ‘requires ‘template<>’ syntax

Tags: c++

I have a templete class and in which i have defined a static object of another class but when I run the code in windows it builds without an error but exactly the same code gives me this error when I build this on linux machine.

> ```
> source.cpp:24:13: error: specializing member ‘classB<int>::Buffer’ requires ‘template<>’ syntax
> ```

```
using namespace std;

template<class T>
struct classA {

  T a;
public:
  classA(int size)
  {
    a = size;
  }
};


template<class T>
struct classB {
  classA<int> static Buffer;
  T a;

};

classA<int> classB<int>::Buffer(120);
int main()
{
  classB<int> Recorder;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
classA<int> classB<int>::Buffer(120)
```

must be changed to

```
template<class T> classA<int> classB<T>::Buffer(120)
```

The classA can take any type, not only int. You have defined it only for int, The other compiler (Linux) could find there an error.

Comment: The classA can take *any* type, not only `int`. You have defined it only for `int`, The other compiler (Linux) could find there an error.

Comment: I'd also tell that the former look like a specialization to the eyes of the compiler. That's why it complain about missing `template<>`